# Trackpy DriftPredict drift parameter

Tags: python, trackpy

DrifPredict signature is "DriftPredict(initial_guess, span)" with the comment :

*initial_guess : Array of length d. Otherwise assumed to be zero velocity.

span : integer, default 1
        Compute velocity field from the most recent span+1 frames.*

So I know that I have to give a 2 element array as drift in a 2D plane.... but I don't know which element is "x" (or "y"). So I looked into the source code ( https://github.com/soft-matter/trackpy/blob/master/trackpy/predict.py ) and found that internaly, the drift is a pandas.dataframe converted into a numpy array... but not further.

Maybe someone can tell me the standard order of x and y in trackpy.predict ?

*general information*:

The python module Trackpy allow to link particles into trajectory. 
When the particle density is high, linking needs a good initial guess to find the right particle in the next frame.
I know my particles have a very deterministic drift along "x" which is near the standard distance between particles, that's why I need to use DriftPredict

Answer (score 1):

A I wrote the question, I dove deeper into the source code.
I found 

`self.pos_columns = kw.get('pos_columns', ['x', 'y'])`

 which is used in calculating the drift.

So I guess the initial_guess parameter should be `np.array(x,y)` (or directly `(x,y)` because it is converted into a numpy.array in the "DriftPredict" object)